# Testdome - DecoratorStream Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to solve the problem at the link [here](https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/decorator-stream/22566). My solution runs into a stackoverflow error on testdome, although it works when I run it in my IDE.

My solution:

```
private static boolean prefixused;

@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    byte [] prefixarr = new byte [prefix.length()+b.length];

    if(prefixused)
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    else
        for(char c : prefix.toCharArray()){
            write((int)c);
        }

        write(prefixarr, 0, prefixarr.length);
        prefixused = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling write instead of stream.write (this is part of the task). It should not throw error if it is like this:

```
@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if(prefixused)
        stream.write(b, 0, b.length);
    else
        for(char c : prefix.toCharArray()){
            stream.write((int)c);
        }

    stream.write(b, off, len);
        prefixused = true;
}
```

But this solution passes all tests and is more elegant:

```
@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (prefix != null) {
        stream.write(prefix.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        prefix = null;
    }
    stream.write(b, off, len);
}
```